# Can't get python script to recognize PyQt5 MainWindow class from import

Tags: python-3.x, module, pyqt5

I'm trying to set a variable in a python scripts based on the numerical input of a lineEdit widget in the PyQt file.

However I cannot get the python script to recognize the Mainwindow class to call upon the number from the 'number' module in Mainwindow.

```
#main_file

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
   
        
    def number(self):
        # return text value of line edit
        return self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.show()
    
    app.exec_()
```

---

```
import main_file
class Row_number:
    number = 604

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.number)
row_number = Row_number()

def initialize():
    row_number.number = main_file.widget.number
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: module 'main_file' has no attribute 'widget'
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` is only executed if the file is executed from command line

the code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` is not executed when it is imported to other file, that is the purpose of `if __name__ == '__main__':` this conditional statement

so if you want to access widget then import the class `MainWindow` to other file create it's instance and then access the variables inside of it